# How do I get the caller Form's name in the Insert() of a table in AX 2012?

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How do I get the caller Form's name in the Insert() of a table in AX 2012?

Comment: You need to someting of what you have done so far.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `dataSource`'s `formRun`.

```cs
FormDataSource fds;
FormName fn;

if (this.isFormDataSource())
{
    fds = this.dataSource() as FormDataSource;

    if (fds)
    {
        fn = fds.formRun().name();
    }
}
```